# Use response of call later once request complete [jquery, ajax, codeigniter]

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How to use response of function edit_book so I could add selected attribute to subcategory field in the form? I'm using condeigniter3, jquery and bootstrap.

Here's how my code works:
Form opens in modal, function edit_book gets data about the selected book (get_row controller), another piece populates subcategories based on category field change (populate_subcats controller). So both controllers get data from different tables in database.

What I want? If books.book_subcat = book_subcats.subcat_id add selected attribute to one of the options in book subcategory select field.

Hints? The say I could use jQuery.parseJSON( json )

```
/*populate subcats on cat change*/
$('#book_cat').change(function(){
    var subcat_id = $(this).val();
    
    var book_subcat = "<?php echo site_url('book/get_row/') ?>" + "<?php $book->book_id ?>]"; //added this line
    
    $("#book_subcat > option").remove();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('book/populate_subcats'); ?>",//controller
        data: {id: subcat_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(k, v){
               var opt = $('<option />');
                opt.val(k);
                opt.text(v);
                $('#book_subcat').append(opt);          
                    //added lines below
var json = $.parseJSON(book_subcat);
$(json).each(function (i, val) {
  $.each(val, function (k, v) {
     if (book_subcat == v.subcat_id) {
                $('select[name="book_subcat"]').append('<option value="' + v.subcat_id + '" selected>' + v.subcat_name + '</option>').trigger('change');
            } else {
                $('select[name="book_subcat"]').append('<option value="' + v.subcat_id + '">' + v.subcat_name + '</option>');
            }
  });
}); 
                //added lines above
            });
        }
    });
});
//get book data
  function edit_book(id) {
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $.ajax({ //Load data from ajax
      url: "<?php echo site_url('book/get_row/') ?>" + id,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        $('[name="book_cat"]').val(data.book_cat).trigger('change'); //new
        $('[name="book_subcat"]').val(data.book_subcat).trigger('change'); //new
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
      }
    })
  }



//Database structure:
TABLE `books` (
`book_id`
`book_cat` = refers to table book_cats
`book_subcat`  = refers to table book_subcats)

TABLE `book_cats` (
`cat_id`
`cat_name`

TABLE `book_subcats` (
`subcat_id`
`subcat_name`
`parent_id` = refers to table book_cats)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the options and check the values of options as you go
where if the value matches book add attribute using `.attr()`

```
$("#books option").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "1"){ 
       $(this ).attr("selected","");
    }
})
```

and you can make this a function were it runs every time the book id changes

Alternativly, you can use

```
$("#books").val("1").change();
```

but this solution won't have the selected attribute if need to use it later